# Error when crawling with permissions problems

Tags: ros, permissions

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I have a ros package that I want to access via roscd using autocompletion. But, for some weird configuration of our lab, I don't have permissions to see the files of a directory, thought I can access to one folder.

Example,
I have my packages in:

```
/home/robot/rych/catking_ws/src
```

And I have no problem accessing or crawling there, but I don't have permissions in the folder:

```
/home/robot
```

So I get the error (warning actually):

```
Warning: error while crawling /home/robot: boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: Permission denied: "/home/robot"
```

And this is really annoying, there is a way to disable this Warning?
Or even better, there is a way to tell ros to not crawl into this specific folder? (allowing to crawl inside the package folder only)

Edit: I add the content of CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH and ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

```
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = /home/robot/rych/catkin_ws/devel:/home/robot/rych/PhaROS-ws/devel:/opt/ros/indigo

ROS_PACKAGE_PATH = /home/robot/rych/catkin_ws/src:/home/robot/rych/PhaROS-ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224134/error-when-crawling-with-permissions-problems/) by [mcamp](https://answers.ros.org/users/14646/mcamp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-01-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-14**:
What do you have your CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH and your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variables set to? You might be able to adjust those to control the package search crawing behavior.

**Comment by [mcamp](https://answers.ros.org/users/14646/mcamp/) on 2016-01-15**:
I edited the question to show the content of both variables, can you see how to solve this with that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tab-completion for roscd eventually calls rospack; and that startup for rospack tries to query if the current directory is within a ROS package or not, by walking up from the current directory to /, looking for a package.xml.

It looks like this is a bug in rospack, and I don't see a good way to suppress it without modifying rospack. You should file an issue on the [rospack issue tracker](https://github.com/ros/rospack/issues).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mcamp](https://answers.ros.org/users/14646/mcamp/) on 2016-01-15**:
I see, thanks for that
I will file this issue then